# Как в else отобразить не добавленные элементы в DRF

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Добавляю через файл записи в модель. Через post передается xls файл, парсится и добавляются значение в бд.  С помощью исключения происходит проверка на наличие имеющихся записей в базе, записываются только те записи, которые отсутствуют.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно написать else для отображения в json записей, которые уже имелись и не добавились.

```
def post(self, request):
    file = request.FILES['file_data']
    file_data = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=file.read())
    sheet = file_data.sheet_by_index(0)
    
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        if row == 0:
            continue
        try:
            device_found = Device.objects.get(inventory_number=str(sheet.row_values(row)[2])
        except Device.DoesNotExist:
            device = Device()
            device.name = sheet.row_values(row)[0]
            device.inventory_number = sheet.row_values(row)[2]
        else:
            # требуемый код
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял "*для отображения ... записей, которые уже имелись и не добавились*" и пример приведенного кода, вы `try except`-ами пытаетесь сделать то, что делает встроенный метод [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Он возвращает кортеж из (object, created), где:

- `object` - полученный или созданный объект
- `created` - булевое значение, равное True, если была создана новая запись...

Тогда обход строк можно организовать как-то так:

```py
existed = []
# existed = {}
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):  # начало цикла с 1 избавит от if row == 0: continue
    obj, created = Device.objects.get_or_create(
        name=sheet.row_values(row)[0],
        inventory_number=sheet.row_values(row)[2]
    )
    if not created:
        existed.append({
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name,
            'number': obj.inventory_number
        })
        # existed[obj.id] = {
        #     'name': obj.name, 
        #     'number': obj.inventory_number
        # }
```

на выходе которого у вас будет <del>словарь</del> список словарей `existed` с данными о записях, который уже были в базе.

Comment: лучше наверное сделать existed списком и добавлять данные через append. В Вашем случае будут постоянно данные обновляться, и списка из значений не получится. либо просто писать `existed[obj.id] = {'name': obj.name, 'number': obj.inventory_number}`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov спасибо!